How to always read from the end of the topic while using Confluent .NET API
I have a .NET Consumer of a Kafka topic that uses the Confluent .NET API. I want to always read from the end of the topic.
For example, if the Consumer disconnects for a while and then reconnects, I want to pick up the messages from the end of the topic and do not want to receive messages that were added to the topic between the disconnect and reconnect.
Following code seems to work, but I am not sure if I am doing the right way. If there is another better way to do this, please let me know.
 public static void SetOffsetToEnd(IConsumer<Ignore, string> consumer, string topicName)
 {
     List<string> topics = new List<string> { topicName };


     consumer.Assign(topics.Select(topic => new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, 0, Offset.End)).ToList());

     var offsets = consumer.Assignment.Select(partition => new TopicPartitionOffset(partition, Offset.End));
     foreach (var offset in offsets)
     {
         consumer.Seek(offset);
     }
 }

 public static void Main()
 {
     ConsumerConfig consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig
     {
         BootstrapServers = "",
         SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.ScramSha512,
         SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
         SaslUsername = "",
         SaslPassword = "",
         GroupId = $"{Environment.MachineName}",
         AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest
         
     };



     using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(consumerConfig).Build())
     {
         String topic = "decline_and_fall_of_roman_empire";
         consumer.Subscribe(topic);

         SetOffsetToEnd(consumer, topic);
         Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());

         while (true)
         {
             var consumeResult = consumer.Consume();
             Console.WriteLine($"Consumed message '{consumeResult.Message.Value}' at: '{consumeResult.TopicPartitionOffset}'.");
             Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
         }

     }


 }



You can just disable offset commits, then configure the consumer with AutoOffsetReset  set to latest (which is the default).

How do I do that? Is it by setting EnableAutoCommit to False? I tried that and it did not help.

Yes. Also don't manually commit your offsets, if you are. Can you show a [mcve] of your full code to show what didn't work?

I have added the fully functional code to the initial post.

Thanks. Can you clarify what you meant by "did not help"? Did you already have offsets saved for your GroupId? If so, then AutoOffsetReset doesn't do anything and you would need to seek. Otherwise, you need a new groupId

What is happening when I just use EnableAutoCommit to false without doing the seek as in the code above, I get all messages that arrived on the topic between the client's disconnect and reconnect. As I mentioned before, I want the Client to only get the messages that were added after the reconnect.

It should adhere to the auto.offset.reset option if a group doesn't exist. You could generate a random group id each time to guarantee this

I thought using a random group id is a bad idea.  Does not it create a whole bunch of consumer groups? I assume those are not resource intensive since it is just a pointer.

It's fine. kafka-console-consumer also creates random groups. If you don't commit the offsets, the the consumer-offsets topic isn't updated; it's just to prevent lookups of any existing group names, since you do have GroupId = set in the code already

Thank you, your suggested approach of not committing the offset works well. However, there is a few seconds' delay in receiving the first message from the topic when compared to the offset reset method in the code above. The method you suggested is simple and easy to use; however, the delay is an issue in my use case. I am implementing a solution where a subscription request is sent, and as soon as it is received by the server, it publishes a cached list of prices. If the consumer is slow, it will miss the complete set of prices in the cache.
